# IntelliJ: How to import a folder of .java files as a library?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-money

It's probably a stupid question, but I can't figure out how to properly import a folder of `.java` files as a library into my IntelliJ project.

I am trying to use the JavaMoney API, which I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api).

I know that the normal way would be *File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > + JARs or Directories*, yet that always adds an "Empty Library" to the list, which is nowhere to be seen in the Project View.

Could someone set me on the right track here?

Comment: If you aren't using Gradle or Maven, you can add any 3rd party JAR you wish to a directory /lib and add that to your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the sources directly. You should start to use maven (or gradle). In that case you can simply add a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.money</groupId>
    <artifactId>money-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't want to use maven, you should import the existing maven project from the repository and export it as a *.jar file.

Or you simply download the prebuilt version from a [mvn-repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.money/money-api/1.0.1).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found the repository. I'm only a beginner, I still have to look into build management.

Comment: Although perfectly correct and the only sensible thing to do, and upvoted from me, this should be a comment really. It is just that the question is very poor, but the "correct" answer to the actual question would be to import those files as a module within a project.

Comment: "perfectly correct" - yes.  Seeing these faux moderator comments that answer nothing and provide no value from low rep users drives me crazy.